# Ruby on Rails 3 simple grouping and counting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, count, grouping

Say I have a 'Car' object which contains a 'color' column. I want in my view a listing of color with the number of times it has appeared.

```
---Car----Color---
Explorer Black
Charger  Yellow
Prius    Black
Jetta    Black
Ferrari  Red 
Pinto    Yellow
```

In my view, I want:

```
--Color--Count--
Black      3
Yellow     2
Red        1
```

In my controller I tried making a list like:

```
@colorcount = Car.all.count(:group => :color)
```

and then in my view I have something like

```
<%= @colorcount.each do |car, count| %>
   <%= car.color %>, <%= count %>
<% end %>
```

but I'm getting an error like:

```
undefined method `each' for 0:Fixnum
```

Is there a lot more to this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@groups = Car.count(:group=>:color)

<% @groups.each do |color,count| %>
  <%= "#{color}, #{count}" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I was close! The answer that got deleted also worked. Thanks to both of you. I added sorting by this: @groups = Car.count(:group => :color, :order => 'count_all DESC')